# How to require password to change other user specific settings (not just change password) with Firebase SimpleLogin

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

For the Firebase simple login we have the changePassword method which requires the old password to be provided before the new one is set.

I would like to add a feature to my app where the current password is required to change other user specific parameters (like the email address or user name), but not necessarily at the time of setting a new password.

What is the best way to go about doing this if it is currently possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Presumably, you want to do this while already authenticated? I'd bet you could use a hidden iframe and call new FirebaseSimpleLogin().login() to test a password without affecting the current login?

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] There's no way to do this currently - short of logging the user out and back in - but I'd love to get your thoughts / feedback on how we could best implement this for you.